# Why is there no & in the scan function?

Tags: c, function

This is the programm I wrote:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void meanVariance(double* x, int n, double* mean, double* variance);
double* scanVector(int length);


void meanVariance(double* x, int n, double* mean, double* variance){
    double sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        sum += x[i];
    }

    *mean = sum / ((double)n);

    sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        double sq = x[i] - *mean;
        sum += sq * sq;
    }

    if (n != 1)
    {
        *variance = sum / ((double)n );
    }
    else
    {
        *variance = 1;
    }

}


int main() {
    double *x = malloc(sizeof(double)), mean = 0, variance = 0;
    int n = 0;
    do {
        n++;
        x = realloc(x, sizeof(double) * (n));
        printf("Type in the %d- Number 


: ", n);
        scanf("%lf", (x+(n-1)));
        meanVariance(x, n, &mean, &variance);
        printf("Mittelwert: %f\n", mean);
        printf("Varianz: %f\n", variance);
    } while(*(x+(n-1)) != 0);
    free(x);
}
```

I don't unterstand why there is no & in the scanf function. The program works but I just don't unterstand why cause the & is missing. I'm guessing it has something to do with the pointer x however i'm not sure at all.

Comment: hint: x+(n-1) is the same as &x[n-1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x+(n-1)` - this is *pointer arithmetic* (study the term).

The `[]` operator is specified with the guarantee that `array[i]` (readable) is 100% equivalent to `*((array) + (i))` (unreadable).

In your case `&x[n-1]` is the same as `&*( (x) + (n-1) )`. The `&` and `*` cancel each other out and what remains is `x + (n-1)`.

So we can unslopify the code using readable form like this: `scanf("%lf", &x[n-1]);`

Answer (score 3):

You only need `&` if you need to take the address of a value, that is, produce a pointer to that value. But `x` is already a pointer, so there is no need for `&`. It would be quite wrong to use `&` in this case, because you'd end up with a pointer to a pointer!

There is also some pointer arithmetic going on: `x+(n-1)` advances the pointer by `n-1` positions in memory, each position being `sizeof(double)` bytes. If you view `x` as an array, it's the same as `&x[n-1]`; that is, the address of the `n-1`th element in the array.